# JavaScript (background and sound change to all pages) help needed

Tags: javascript

For my final project for a course I want to make some kind of minimalistic, meditation/relaxation website but I'm struggling with coding the JS functions. I'll try to explain the steps for what I want to do:

1. The page starts out with a white background.
2. Text fades in. (i.e. "Welcome")
3. When a key is pressed or the screen is tapped on mobile, the previous text fades out and another text fades in, but still on the same page.
4. Another text later, with options below for the background. When an option is clicked, the background changes and again, the text fades out.
5. Same as #4, but with background music.
6. Then there are 3 routes to go to (so different pages), the codes for those are simple so I don't need a lot of help, but how do I make them so that the background image and the sound that the user has chosen, carries on?

Is this completely doable with only JavaScript?
Should I incorporate Flask in my program (i.e. HTML layout/template?)

I'm really lost :( Does anyone know which functions I could use? Help will be appreciated!

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3001761) I'd recommend reading [ask].

Comment: @upvoters I'd also suggest *you* read [ask]

Comment: I think you should read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions, and I also think for continuous music you would better incorporate all pages into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you could achieve this result by using only javascript**

You can send the user's selected background and music through query parameters and access them with `url` in your javascript of other pages.

Comment: Ohk, I was just trying to help.